# Why does $(this).text() return "" after click on li?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

Why does this return a blank string "" on click event?

```
function saveSelection()
{
    var selectedValue = $(this).text(); // --> is ""
}
```

for

```
<ul>
   <li data-bind="item" onclick="saveSelection();">Value1</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this as parameter:

```
function saveSelection(element)
{
    var selectedValue = $(element).text(); // --> is "Value1"
}
```

for

```
<ul>
   <li data-bind="item" onclick="saveSelection(this);">Value1</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: OR, since he's using jQuery, he could kill the inline function call and then the param becomes `event`. Call it like `$("li[data-bind=item]").on("click", saveSelection);` or use as a delegate for ***dynamic*** input. Such as `$("ul#ulID").on("click", "li[data-bind=item]", saveSelection);`

Answer (score 2):

The context in a function depends on how it is called, the way you called `saveSelection`, `this` will be the global object (`window`). You can set the context of a function with the [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) method

```
<li data-bind="item" onclick="saveSelection.call(this);">Value1</li><!-- `this` is the li here. -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Just my 2 cents...

<sub>Cation: This answer diving into jQuery may make references to other items' use in jQuery "mark-up". This doesn't mean they invented the system, only that they made it better. Caution: This might sometimes be spelled out in "layman's terms" so "Everyone" can learn the power available to them.</sub>

There are several ways to right this wrong, each with it's own pro and con.

The first obvious is, as suggested already, simply pass `this` as a parameter. The pro to this is good old fashioned inline editing. You know exactly where each line of that is written. The cons are plenty. First of all, if you change that function name, then it must be changed everywhere it's called, and with inline editing, that could be a lot of places. Also, you lose the flexibility of staying dynamic and being able to  make "easy" changes at will. The list goes on and on, but long story short, there's a reason this is called an "old" method.

How it works:

```
//  here "this" is passed as a parameter/argument to the method you're calling
<li data-bind="item" onclick="saveSelection(this);">Value1</li>
//  so in your method, simply get the parameter or argument
function saveSelection(element)
```

Another way is to use the good old jQuery .click() method. Of course this requires know what element to apply it to. While you're li seems slightly ambiguous, it does have a give away. The "data-bind" property. We can use this property to get all li's containing that property and assign the click method to them. However, when doen this way, your parameter becomes a jQuery event object as opposed to "this". However, "this" is still implied, thus it still exist within the function. The pro here is no need to pass "this", it's already there! The con, if li's containing data-bind=item are added after this code is run, they won't be assigned this method, as they are "late to the party".

```
$("li[data-bind=item]").click(saveSelection);
//  Also same as 
$("li[data-bind=item]").on("click", saveSelection);
```

Finally, the better solution.  The before method last mentioned contains an "alternate" version known as "[**delegate**](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)". This allows you to set an event to all elements of your selector, despite when they are created! This means, even late li elements containing our selector will still be assigned the click method! The only con I can think of, this only seem to work best when using a parent ID that must exist before this call is made. The parent should be a direct parent of the child.

```
//  In other words it works like this
$("#parentID").on("click", ".child-class", function(e) {});
```

For your example, if you assigned UL the ID of "bob", then it would look like so:

```
$("#bob").on("click", "li[data-bind=item]", saveSelection);
```

And of course your function param would change too:

```
function saveSelection(event) {
    var $this = $(this); // note, this is already passed through!!!
```

With jQuery, there is no "correct" solution, just opportunity. So sit back, relax, try a few things and find what works best for your needs! Enjoy!

Comment: `this` isn't passed through to a callback/handler. `this` is a JS keyword, that referenced the current call context, and has nothing to do with jQuery, either. if you call a function in the global namespace, `this` will either point to the global object (most commonly referred to as `window`) or null (strict mode). _delegate_ is no jQ invention either, event delegation has been around since donkey's years. You seem to suggest as though it's a jQ goodie

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
   <li data-bind="item" onclick="saveSelection(event);">Value1</li>
</ul>

function saveSelection(e)
{  
    var selectedValue = $(e.target).text(); // --> is ""
  console.log(selectedValue);
}
```